# Сreate a dictionary from a zip of 3 lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have 3 lists that I would like to put into a dictionary:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list3 = [0.5, 0.3, 0.1]
```

Traditionally I could create a dictionary like this with just `list1`, `list2`

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list1, list2))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

But what I would like to get is:

```
{'a': (1, 0.5), 'b': (2, 0.3), 'c': (3, 0.1)}
```

This did not work:

```
my_dict = dict(list1, zip(list2, list3))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add one more zip, since `dict` constructor accepts list of `tuple`s, but not two `list`s:

```
my_dict_3 = dict(zip(list1, zip(list2, list3)))
```