# How to use tuple as a key of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have three lists :

```
gene = [gene_1, gene_2] 
number = [1, 2] 
list_third = ['atcatcg', 'atcatcg']
```

I want to create a dictionary and I want the key of this dictionary to be tuple containing the element of my first list and second list (gene and number) and the value will be the sequences

I want my output to be like:

```
dict = {(gene_1, 1):'atcatcg', (gene_2, 2):'atcatcg'}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Сreate a dictionary from a zip of 3 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930844/%d0%a1reate-a-dictionary-from-a-zip-of-3-lists) (to adopt the given solution to keys instead of values is trivial)

Answer (score 9):

Use the `dict` constructor and `zip`... twice:

```
>>> dict(zip(zip(gene, number), list_third))
{('gene_2', 2): 'atcatcg', ('gene_1', 1): 'atcatcg'}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
gene = ['gene_1', 'gene_2']
number = [1, 2]
list_third = ['atcatcg', 'atcatcg']

result = {tuple(key) : value for *key, value in  zip(gene, number, list_third)}

print(result)
```

Or, as an alternative:

```
result = {(gene, number) : value for gene, number, value in  zip(gene, number, list_third)}
```

Comment: Minor improvement is to let another layer of `zip` make the `tuple`s directly: `{key: value for key, value in zip(zip(gene, number), list_third)}`. And of course, that leaves the `dict` comprehension doing nothing special, so you could just make it `dict(zip(zip(gene, number), list_third))`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That is an alternative solution, but I thought flat was better that nested. Anyway if the dict constructor is faster your solution is the way to go.

Comment: @RaySteam: It's definitely faster, but that's not the be-all, end-all criteria. I personally like your second `dict` comprehension for resisting the urge to use junk names, instead using meaningful names and making it clear how they repack (it's likely faster than your first solution to boot, though slightly slower than `dict` of nested `zip`).

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over the three lists

  - this will produce (gene,number,sequence) tuples
- [extract `gene` and `number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) for the key and use the sequence for the value.